# Не получается в категориях вывести опции opencart

Tags: php, opencart

Добрый день, друзья, столкнулся с такой проблемкой: на странице категории хочу вывести при ховере на блок опцию этого элемента, к примеру, размер. Добавляю в файл category.php следующие строки:

```
$data['options'] = array();
        foreach ($this->model_catalog_product->getProductOptions($this->request->get['product_id']) as $option) {
            $product_option_value_data = array();
            foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $option_value) {
                if (!$option_value['subtract'] || ($option_value['quantity'] > 0)) {
                    if ((($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) && (float)$option_value['price']) {
                        $price = $this->currency->format(($this->tax->calculate($option_value['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax') ? 'P' : false)), $this->session->data['currency']);
                    } else {
                        $price = false;
                    }
                    $product_option_value_data[] = array(
                        'product_option_value_id' => $option_value['product_option_value_id'],
                        'option_value_id'         => $option_value['option_value_id'],
                        'name'                    => $option_value['name'],
                        'image'                   => $this->ave->cropsize($option_value['image'], 50, 50),
                        'price'                   => $price,
                        'price_prefix'            => $option_value['price_prefix']
                    );
                }
            }
            $data['options'][] = array(
                'product_option_id'    => $option['product_option_id'],
                'product_option_value' => $product_option_value_data,
                'option_id'            => $option['option_id'],
                'name'                 => $option['name'],
                'type'                 => $option['type'],
                'value'                => $option['value'],
                'required'             => $option['required']
            );
        }
```

В category.tpl вывожу следующее:

```
 <?php foreach ($options as $option) { ?>
   <?php if ($option['type'] == 'checkbox') { ?>
     <div class="form-group<?php echo ($option['required'] ? ' required' : ''); ?>">
       <label class="control-label"><?php echo $option['name']; ?></label>
       <div id="input-option<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>">
     <?php foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
        div class="checkbox">
        <label>
       <input type="checkbox" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>][]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" />
        <?php if ($option_value['image']) { ?>
<img src="<?php echo $option_value['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $option_value['name'] . ($option_value['price'] ? ' ' . $option_value['price_prefix'] . $option_value['price'] : ''); ?>" class="img-thumbnail" /> 
       <?php } ?>
      <?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
     <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>(<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
  <?php }
</label>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

В результате на странице категорий ошибка: 
Notice: Undefined variable: options /noraure/template/product/category.tpl
on line 103 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() /noraure/template/product/category.tplon line 103

Как решить — не пойму, ведь $options я объявил в controller, кто знает — подскажите, буду очень признателен!

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57400/discussion-on-question-by-alan-sh-------openc).

Answer (score 0):

Контроллер вот:

```
<?php
class ControllerProductCategory extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->language('product/category');

        $this->load->model('catalog/category');

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        $this->load->model('tool/image');

        if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) {
            $filter = $this->request->get['filter'];
        } else {
            $filter = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $sort = $this->request->get['sort'];
        } else {
            $sort = 'p.sort_order';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $order = $this->request->get['order'];
        } else {
            $order = 'ASC';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
            $page = $this->request->get['page'];
        } else {
            $page = 1;
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
            $limit = (int)$this->request->get['limit'];
        } else {
            $limit = $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_limit');
        }

        $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('common/home')
        );

        if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
            $url = '';

            if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
                $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
            }

            $path = '';

            $parts = explode('_', (string)$this->request->get['path']);

            $category_id = (int)array_pop($parts);

            foreach ($parts as $path_id) {
                if (!$path) {
                    $path = (int)$path_id;
                } else {
                    $path .= '_' . (int)$path_id;
                }

                $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($path_id);

                if ($category_info) {
                    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                        'text' => $category_info['name'],
                        'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $path . $url)
                    );
                }
            }
        } else {
            $category_id = 0;
        }

        $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($category_id);

        if ($category_info) {
            $this->document->setTitle($category_info['meta_title']);
            $this->document->setDescription($category_info['meta_description']);
            $this->document->setKeywords($category_info['meta_keyword']);

            $data['heading_title'] = $category_info['name'];

            $data['text_refine'] = $this->language->get('text_refine');
            $data['text_empty'] = $this->language->get('text_empty');
            $data['text_quantity'] = $this->language->get('text_quantity');
            $data['text_manufacturer'] = $this->language->get('text_manufacturer');
            $data['text_model'] = $this->language->get('text_model');
            $data['text_price'] = $this->language->get('text_price');
            $data['text_tax'] = $this->language->get('text_tax');
            $data['text_points'] = $this->language->get('text_points');
            $data['text_compare'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_compare'), (isset($this->session->data['compare']) ? count($this->session->data['compare']) : 0));
            $data['text_sort'] = $this->language->get('text_sort');
            $data['text_limit'] = $this->language->get('text_limit');

            $data['button_cart'] = $this->language->get('button_cart');
            $data['button_wishlist'] = $this->language->get('button_wishlist');
            $data['button_compare'] = $this->language->get('button_compare');
            $data['button_continue'] = $this->language->get('button_continue');
            $data['button_list'] = $this->language->get('button_list');
            $data['button_grid'] = $this->language->get('button_grid');

            // Set the last category breadcrumb
            $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                'text' => $category_info['name'],
                'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'])
            );

            if ($category_info['image']) {
                $data['thumb'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($category_info['image'], $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_category_width'), $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_category_height'));
            } else {
                $data['thumb'] = '';
            }

            $data['description'] = html_entity_decode($category_info['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
            $data['compare'] = $this->url->link('product/compare');

            $url = '';

            if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) {
                $url .= '&filter=' . $this->request->get['filter'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
                $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
            }

            $data['categories'] = array();

            $results = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category_id);

            foreach ($results as $result) {
                $filter_data = array(
                    'filter_category_id'  => $result['category_id'],
                    'filter_sub_category' => true
                );

                $data['categories'][] = array(
                    'name' => $result['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
                    'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '_' . $result['category_id'] . $url)
                );
            }






            $data['products'] = array();

            $filter_data = array(
                'filter_category_id' => $category_id,
                'filter_filter'      => $filter,
                'sort'               => $sort,
                'order'              => $order,
                'start'              => ($page - 1) * $limit,
                'limit'              => $limit
            );

            $product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data);

            $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($filter_data);

            foreach ($results as $result) {
                if ($result['image']) {
                    $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_width'), $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_height'));
                } else {
                    $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize('placeholder.png', $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_width'), $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_height'));
                }

                if ($this->customer->isLogged() || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                    $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['price'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
                } else {
                    $price = false;
                }

                if ((float)$result['special']) {
                    $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['special'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
                } else {
                    $special = false;
                }

                if ($this->config->get('config_tax')) {
                    $tax = $this->currency->format((float)$result['special'] ? $result['special'] : $result['price'], $this->session->data['currency']);
                } else {
                    $tax = false;
                }

                if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
                    $rating = (int)$result['rating'];
                } else {
                    $rating = false;
                }

            $data['options'] = array();

            foreach ($this->model_catalog_product->getProductOptions($this->request->get['product_id']) as $option) {
                $product_option_value_data = array();

                foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $option_value) {
                    if (!$option_value['subtract'] || ($option_value['quantity'] > 0)) {
                        if ((($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) && (float)$option_value['price']) {
                            $price = $this->currency->format(($this->tax->calculate($option_value['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax') ? 'P' : false)), $this->session->data['currency']);
                        } else {
                            $price = false;
                        }

                        $product_option_value_data[] = array(
                            'product_option_value_id' => $option_value['product_option_value_id'],
                            'option_value_id'         => $option_value['option_value_id'],
                            'name'                    => $option_value['name'],
                            'image'                   => $this->ave->cropsize($option_value['image'], 50, 50),
                            'price'                   => $price,
                            'price_prefix'            => $option_value['price_prefix']
                        );
                    }
                }

                $data['options'][] = array(
                    'product_option_id'    => $option['product_option_id'],
                    'product_option_value' => $product_option_value_data,
                    'option_id'            => $option['option_id'],
                    'name'                 => $option['name'],
                    'type'                 => $option['type'],
                    'value'                => $option['value'],
                    'required'             => $option['required']
                );
            }


                $data['products'][] = array(
                    'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
                    'thumb'       => $image,
                    'name'        => $result['name'],
                    'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_description_length')) . '..',
                    'price'       => $price,
                    'special'     => $special,
                    'tax'         => $tax,
                    'minimum'     => $result['minimum'] > 0 ? $result['minimum'] : 1,
                    'rating'      => $result['rating'],
                    'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&product_id=' . $result['product_id'] . $url)
                );
            }

            $url = '';

            if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) {
                $url .= '&filter=' . $this->request->get['filter'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
                $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
            }

            $data['sorts'] = array();

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_default'),
                'value' => 'p.sort_order-ASC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=p.sort_order&order=ASC' . $url)
            );

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_name_asc'),
                'value' => 'pd.name-ASC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=pd.name&order=ASC' . $url)
            );

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_name_desc'),
                'value' => 'pd.name-DESC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=pd.name&order=DESC' . $url)
            );

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_price_asc'),
                'value' => 'p.price-ASC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=p.price&order=ASC' . $url)
            );

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_price_desc'),
                'value' => 'p.price-DESC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=p.price&order=DESC' . $url)
            );

            if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
                $data['sorts'][] = array(
                    'text'  => $this->language->get('text_rating_desc'),
                    'value' => 'rating-DESC',
                    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=rating&order=DESC' . $url)
                );

                $data['sorts'][] = array(
                    'text'  => $this->language->get('text_rating_asc'),
                    'value' => 'rating-ASC',
                    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=rating&order=ASC' . $url)
                );
            }

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_model_asc'),
                'value' => 'p.model-ASC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=p.model&order=ASC' . $url)
            );

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_model_desc'),
                'value' => 'p.model-DESC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=p.model&order=DESC' . $url)
            );

            $url = '';

            if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) {
                $url .= '&filter=' . $this->request->get['filter'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
            }

            $data['limits'] = array();

            $limits = array_unique(array($this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_limit'), 25, 50, 75, 100));

            sort($limits);

            foreach($limits as $value) {
                $data['limits'][] = array(
                    'text'  => $value,
                    'value' => $value,
                    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . $url . '&limit=' . $value)
                );
            }

            $url = '';

            if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) {
                $url .= '&filter=' . $this->request->get['filter'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
                $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
            }

            $pagination = new Pagination();
            $pagination->total = $product_total;
            $pagination->page = $page;
            $pagination->limit = $limit;
            $pagination->url = $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . $url . '&page={page}');

            $data['pagination'] = $pagination->render();

            $data['results'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_pagination'), ($product_total) ? (($page - 1) * $limit) + 1 : 0, ((($page - 1) * $limit) > ($product_total - $limit)) ? $product_total : ((($page - 1) * $limit) + $limit), $product_total, ceil($product_total / $limit));

            // http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html
            if ($page == 1) {
                $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category_info['category_id'], true), 'canonical');
            } elseif ($page == 2) {
                $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category_info['category_id'], true), 'prev');
            } else {
                $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category_info['category_id'] . '&page='. ($page - 1), true), 'prev');
            }

            if ($limit && ceil($product_total / $limit) > $page) {
                $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category_info['category_id'] . '&page='. ($page + 1), true), 'next');
            }

            $data['sort'] = $sort;
            $data['order'] = $order;
            $data['limit'] = $limit;

            $data['continue'] = $this->url->link('common/home');

            $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
            $data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
            $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
            $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
            $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
            $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');

            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('product/category', $data));
        } else {
            $url = '';

            if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
                $url .= '&path=' . $this->request->get['path'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) {
                $url .= '&filter=' . $this->request->get['filter'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
                $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
                $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
            }

            $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                'text' => $this->language->get('text_error'),
                'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', $url)
            );

            $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('text_error'));

            $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('text_error');

            $data['text_error'] = $this->language->get('text_error');

            $data['button_continue'] = $this->language->get('button_continue');

            $data['continue'] = $this->url->link('common/home');

            $this->response->addHeader($this->request->server['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 404 Not Found');

            $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
            $data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
            $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
            $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
            $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
            $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');

            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('error/not_found', $data));
        }
    }
}
```

я $options объявляю перед   $data['products'][] = array
category.tpl вот:

```
                            <div id="product-layout" class="row">
                                <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
                                <div class="product-layout product-list col-xs-12">

  <!-- Custom block user -->   

                                     <div style="width:100%;height: 400px;background-color: red;opacity: 0.5;">

                                        <?php foreach ($options as $option) { ?>
                                        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'checkbox') { ?>
                                        <div class="form-group<?php echo ($option['required'] ? ' required' : ''); ?>">
                                          <label class="control-label"><?php echo $option['name']; ?></label>
                                          <div id="input-option<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>">
                                            <?php foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                              <label>
                                              <input type="checkbox" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>][]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" />
                                              <?php if ($option_value['image']) { ?>
                                              <img src="<?php echo $option_value['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $option_value['name'] . ($option_value['price'] ? ' ' . $option_value['price_prefix'] . $option_value['price'] : ''); ?>" class="img-thumbnail" /> 
                                              <?php } ?>
                                              <?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
                                              <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
                                              (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
                                              <?php } ?>
                                              </label>
                                            </div>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('product/category.tpl', $data)); ?>
                                        <?php } ?>

                                        <?php } ?>

                                    </div> 

                                    <!-- Custom block user -->


                                    <div class="tb-product-item">
                                        <div class="tb-image">
                                            <?php if ($product['special'] && $ave->get('category_special_label')) { ?>
                                            <span class="special_bg"><?php echo $ave->text('special_label'); ?></span>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                            <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" class="img-responsive" /></a>
                                            <a class="quickview btn-quick-view" data-id="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>" title="<?php echo $ave->text('btn_quickview');?>" data-text="<?php echo $product['name'];?>" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <div class="tb-content">
                                                <div class="tb-product-title"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></div>
                                                <p class="desc"><?php echo $product['description']; ?></p>
                                                <div class="rating"><span class="star-<?php echo $product['rating'];?>"></span></div>
                                                <?php if ($product['price']) { ?>
                                                <div class="tb-product-wrap-price-rating">
                                                    <div class="tb-product-price">
                                                        <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
                                                        <?php echo $product['price']; ?>
                                                        <?php } else { ?>
                                                        <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span> <span class="price-new"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span>
                                                        <?php } ?>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <?php } ?>
                                                <div class="last-cart l-mrgn">
                                                    <?php if($ave->get('category_btn_whistlist')==1){ ?>
                                                    <a class="btn-wishlist other-btn" onclick="wishlist.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a>
                                                    <?php } ?>
                                                    <?php if($ave->get('category_btn_cart')==1){ ?>
                                                    <a class="las4" onclick="cart.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><?php echo $button_cart; ?></a>
                                                    <?php } ?>
                                                    <?php if($ave->get('category_btn_compare')==1){ ?>
                                                    <a class="btn-compare other-btn" onclick="compare.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-retweet"></i></a>
                                                    <?php } ?>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как то так:

```
    <?php
class ControllerProductCategory extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->language('product/category');

        $this->load->model('catalog/category');

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        $this->load->model('tool/image');

        if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) {
            $filter = $this->request->get['filter'];
        } else {
            $filter = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $sort = $this->request->get['sort'];
        } else {
            $sort = 'p.sort_order';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $order = $this->request->get['order'];
        } else {
            $order = 'ASC';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
            $page = $this->request->get['page'];
        } else {
            $page = 1;
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
            $limit = (int)$this->request->get['limit'];
        } else {
            $limit = $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_limit');
        }

        $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('common/home')
        );

        if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
            $url = '';

            if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
                $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
            }

            $path = '';

            $parts = explode('_', (string)$this->request->get['path']);

            $category_id = (int)array_pop($parts);

            foreach ($parts as $path_id) {
                if (!$path) {
                    $path = (int)$path_id;
                } else {
                    $path .= '_' . (int)$path_id;
                }

                $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($path_id);

                if ($category_info) {
                    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                        'text' => $category_info['name'],
                        'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $path . $url)
                    );
                }
            }
        } else {
            $category_id = 0;
        }

        $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($category_id);

        if ($category_info) {
            $this->document->setTitle($category_info['meta_title']);
            $this->document->setDescription($category_info['meta_description']);
            $this->document->setKeywords($category_info['meta_keyword']);

            $data['heading_title'] = $category_info['name'];

            $data['text_refine'] = $this->language->get('text_refine');
            $data['text_empty'] = $this->language->get('text_empty');
            $data['text_quantity'] = $this->language->get('text_quantity');
            $data['text_manufacturer'] = $this->language->get('text_manufacturer');
            $data['text_model'] = $this->language->get('text_model');
            $data['text_price'] = $this->language->get('text_price');
            $data['text_tax'] = $this->language->get('text_tax');
            $data['text_points'] = $this->language->get('text_points');
            $data['text_compare'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_compare'), (isset($this->session->data['compare']) ? count($this->session->data['compare']) : 0));
            $data['text_sort'] = $this->language->get('text_sort');
            $data['text_limit'] = $this->language->get('text_limit');

            $data['button_cart'] = $this->language->get('button_cart');
            $data['button_wishlist'] = $this->language->get('button_wishlist');
            $data['button_compare'] = $this->language->get('button_compare');
            $data['button_continue'] = $this->language->get('button_continue');
            $data['button_list'] = $this->language->get('button_list');
            $data['button_grid'] = $this->language->get('button_grid');

            // Set the last category breadcrumb
            $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                'text' => $category_info['name'],
                'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'])
            );

            if ($category_info['image']) {
                $data['thumb'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($category_info['image'], $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_category_width'), $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_category_height'));
            } else {
                $data['thumb'] = '';
            }

            $data['description'] = html_entity_decode($category_info['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
            $data['compare'] = $this->url->link('product/compare');

            $url = '';

            if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) {
                $url .= '&filter=' . $this->request->get['filter'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
                $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
            }

            $data['categories'] = array();

            $results = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category_id);

            foreach ($results as $result) {
                $filter_data = array(
                    'filter_category_id'  => $result['category_id'],
                    'filter_sub_category' => true
                );

                $data['categories'][] = array(
                    'name' => $result['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
                    'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '_' . $result['category_id'] . $url)
                );
            }






            $data['products'] = array();

            $filter_data = array(
                'filter_category_id' => $category_id,
                'filter_filter'      => $filter,
                'sort'               => $sort,
                'order'              => $order,
                'start'              => ($page - 1) * $limit,
                'limit'              => $limit
            );

            $product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data);

            $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($filter_data);
            $data['options'] = array();

            foreach ($results as $result) {
                if ($result['image']) {
                    $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_width'), $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_height'));
                } else {
                    $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize('placeholder.png', $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_width'), $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_height'));
                }

                if ($this->customer->isLogged() || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                    $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['price'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
                } else {
                    $price = false;
                }

                if ((float)$result['special']) {
                    $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['special'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
                } else {
                    $special = false;
                }

                if ($this->config->get('config_tax')) {
                    $tax = $this->currency->format((float)$result['special'] ? $result['special'] : $result['price'], $this->session->data['currency']);
                } else {
                    $tax = false;
                }

                if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
                    $rating = (int)$result['rating'];
                } else {
                    $rating = false;
                }

                $options = array();

                foreach ($this->model_catalog_product->getProductOptions($this->request->get['product_id']) as $option) {
                    $product_option_value_data = array();

                    foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $option_value) {
                        if (!$option_value['subtract'] || ($option_value['quantity'] > 0)) {
                            if ((($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) && (float)$option_value['price']) {
                                $price = $this->currency->format(($this->tax->calculate($option_value['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax') ? 'P' : false)), $this->session->data['currency']);
                            } else {
                                $price = false;
                            }

                            $product_option_value_data[] = array(
                                'product_option_value_id' => $option_value['product_option_value_id'],
                                'option_value_id'         => $option_value['option_value_id'],
                                'name'                    => $option_value['name'],
                                'image'                   => $this->ave->cropsize($option_value['image'], 50, 50),
                                'price'                   => $price,
                                'price_prefix'            => $option_value['price_prefix']
                            );
                        }
                    }

                    $options[] = array(
                        'product_option_id'    => $option['product_option_id'],
                        'product_option_value' => $product_option_value_data,
                        'option_id'            => $option['option_id'],
                        'name'                 => $option['name'],
                        'type'                 => $option['type'],
                        'value'                => $option['value'],
                        'required'             => $option['required']
                    );
                }


                $data['products'][] = array(
                    'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
                    'thumb'       => $image,
                    'name'        => $result['name'],
                    'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_description_length')) . '..',
                    'price'       => $price,
                    'special'     => $special,
                    'tax'         => $tax,
                    'options'     => $options,
                    'minimum'     => $result['minimum'] > 0 ? $result['minimum'] : 1,
                    'rating'      => $result['rating'],
                    'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&product_id=' . $result['product_id'] . $url)
                );
            }

            $url = '';

            if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) {
                $url .= '&filter=' . $this->request->get['filter'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
                $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
            }

            $data['sorts'] = array();

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_default'),
                'value' => 'p.sort_order-ASC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=p.sort_order&order=ASC' . $url)
            );

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_name_asc'),
                'value' => 'pd.name-ASC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=pd.name&order=ASC' . $url)
            );

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_name_desc'),
                'value' => 'pd.name-DESC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=pd.name&order=DESC' . $url)
            );

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_price_asc'),
                'value' => 'p.price-ASC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=p.price&order=ASC' . $url)
            );

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_price_desc'),
                'value' => 'p.price-DESC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=p.price&order=DESC' . $url)
            );

            if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
                $data['sorts'][] = array(
                    'text'  => $this->language->get('text_rating_desc'),
                    'value' => 'rating-DESC',
                    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=rating&order=DESC' . $url)
                );

                $data['sorts'][] = array(
                    'text'  => $this->language->get('text_rating_asc'),
                    'value' => 'rating-ASC',
                    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=rating&order=ASC' . $url)
                );
            }

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_model_asc'),
                'value' => 'p.model-ASC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=p.model&order=ASC' . $url)
            );

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_model_desc'),
                'value' => 'p.model-DESC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=p.model&order=DESC' . $url)
            );

            $url = '';

            if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) {
                $url .= '&filter=' . $this->request->get['filter'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
            }

            $data['limits'] = array();

            $limits = array_unique(array($this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_limit'), 25, 50, 75, 100));

            sort($limits);

            foreach($limits as $value) {
                $data['limits'][] = array(
                    'text'  => $value,
                    'value' => $value,
                    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . $url . '&limit=' . $value)
                );
            }

            $url = '';

            if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) {
                $url .= '&filter=' . $this->request->get['filter'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
                $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
            }

            $pagination = new Pagination();
            $pagination->total = $product_total;
            $pagination->page = $page;
            $pagination->limit = $limit;
            $pagination->url = $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . $url . '&page={page}');

            $data['pagination'] = $pagination->render();

            $data['results'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_pagination'), ($product_total) ? (($page - 1) * $limit) + 1 : 0, ((($page - 1) * $limit) > ($product_total - $limit)) ? $product_total : ((($page - 1) * $limit) + $limit), $product_total, ceil($product_total / $limit));

            // http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html
            if ($page == 1) {
                $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category_info['category_id'], true), 'canonical');
            } elseif ($page == 2) {
                $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category_info['category_id'], true), 'prev');
            } else {
                $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category_info['category_id'] . '&page='. ($page - 1), true), 'prev');
            }

            if ($limit && ceil($product_total / $limit) > $page) {
                $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category_info['category_id'] . '&page='. ($page + 1), true), 'next');
            }

            $data['sort'] = $sort;
            $data['order'] = $order;
            $data['limit'] = $limit;

            $data['continue'] = $this->url->link('common/home');

            $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
            $data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
            $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
            $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
            $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
            $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');

            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('product/category', $data));
        } else {
            $url = '';

            if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
                $url .= '&path=' . $this->request->get['path'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) {
                $url .= '&filter=' . $this->request->get['filter'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
                $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
                $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
            }

            $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                'text' => $this->language->get('text_error'),
                'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', $url)
            );

            $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('text_error'));

            $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('text_error');

            $data['text_error'] = $this->language->get('text_error');

            $data['button_continue'] = $this->language->get('button_continue');

            $data['continue'] = $this->url->link('common/home');

            $this->response->addHeader($this->request->server['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 404 Not Found');

            $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
            $data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
            $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
            $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
            $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
            $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');

            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('error/not_found', $data));
        }
    }
}
```

tpl:

```
    <div id="product-layout" class="row">
    <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
    <div class="product-layout product-list col-xs-12">

        <!-- Custom block user -->

        <div style="width:100%;height: 400px;background-color: red;opacity: 0.5;">

            <?php foreach ($product['options'] as $option) { ?>
            <?php if ($option['type'] == 'checkbox') { ?>
            <div class="form-group<?php echo ($option['required'] ? ' required' : ''); ?>">
                <label class="control-label"><?php echo $option['name']; ?></label>
                <div id="input-option<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>">
                    <?php foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>][]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" />
                            <?php if ($option_value['image']) { ?>
                            <img src="<?php echo $option_value['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $option_value['name'] . ($option_value['price'] ? ' ' . $option_value['price_prefix'] . $option_value['price'] : ''); ?>" class="img-thumbnail" />
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
                            <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
                            (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
                            <?php } ?>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('product/category.tpl', $data)); ?>
            <?php } ?>

            <?php } ?>

        </div>

        <!-- Custom block user -->


        <div class="tb-product-item">
            <div class="tb-image">
                <?php if ($product['special'] && $ave->get('category_special_label')) { ?>
                <span class="special_bg"><?php echo $ave->text('special_label'); ?></span>
                <?php } ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" class="img-responsive" /></a>
                <a class="quickview btn-quick-view" data-id="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>" title="<?php echo $ave->text('btn_quickview');?>" data-text="<?php echo $product['name'];?>" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="tb-content">
                    <div class="tb-product-title"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></div>
                    <p class="desc"><?php echo $product['description']; ?></p>
                    <div class="rating"><span class="star-<?php echo $product['rating'];?>"></span></div>
                    <?php if ($product['price']) { ?>
                    <div class="tb-product-wrap-price-rating">
                        <div class="tb-product-price">
                            <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
                            <?php echo $product['price']; ?>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                            <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span> <span class="price-new"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <div class="last-cart l-mrgn">
                        <?php if($ave->get('category_btn_whistlist')==1){ ?>
                        <a class="btn-wishlist other-btn" onclick="wishlist.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <?php if($ave->get('category_btn_cart')==1){ ?>
                        <a class="las4" onclick="cart.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><?php echo $button_cart; ?></a>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <?php if($ave->get('category_btn_compare')==1){ ?>
                        <a class="btn-compare other-btn" onclick="compare.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-retweet"></i></a>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: тоже самое выходит(((

Comment: а точно `$this->load->view('product/category', $data)` попадаешь а не в else ?

Comment: да точно, эта опция существует. Мне кажется что просто напросто с контроллера не цепляется $options

Comment: А можешь просто оставить в методе index()  только эту строчку  `$this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('product/category', array('options' => 'test')));`  а в  шаблоне вывести $options

Comment: Короче опции вывел я, но теперь другая проблема. Если я включаю фильтр на странице категорий то опять та же ошибка, как быть теперь уж точно не знаю!

Comment: а фильтр Вы как включаете? Контроллер загружаете, или в этом же контроллере ифами разруливаете?

Comment: Да, фильтр это отдельный контроллер

Comment: В фильтре тоже необходимо выводить options. Так понимаю фильтр  выводится в текущем контроллере , что то типа  `$data['filter'] = $this->load->controller('common/filter');`, а в самом фильтре есть filter.tpl где выводишь options

Comment: Так вот в контроллере `FIlterContriller` тоже должна быть переменная $data['options']

Comment: Все сделал, спасибо огромное за помощь!!!